# How to target a textarea(child) inside a div(parent)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I wanted to add a name attribute on a `textarea` inside the `div`.

So my `div` has an `id` of `textAreaEmail`.

Here's the syntax I've tried:

```
$(textAreaEmail).removeAttr('hidden');
$(textAreaEmail).children('textarea').attr('name', 'body');
```

Here's my `HTML`, I used Form Helpers.

```
<div id="textAreaEmail">
    <div class="form-group <?php echo ($form->error('body') ? 'has-error' : ''); ?>">
        <?php echo label_tag('Body', 'body', true, array('class' => 'control-label'), ''); ?>
        <?php echo textarea_field('body', $form->getField('body'), array(
            'class' => 'form-control' . ($form->error('body') ? ' is-invalid' : ''),
            'required' => true,
            'id' => 'tinymce'
        )); ?>
        <p class="help-block invalid-feedback"><?php echo ($form->error('body') ? $form->error('body') : ''); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not show us the HTML?

Comment: Can you provide us the HTML in order to help you?

Comment: With jQuery or pure javascript?

Comment: `children()` looks only for child elements. If the `textarea` is a grandchild of the `div` (or lower) then you'll need to use `find()` instead

Comment: With jQuery. @Hanif

Comment: This is wrong `$(textAreaEmail)` You forgot to identify what is, and in this case you have an id which means that the right thing is: `$("#textAreaEmail").removeAttr('hidden');
$("#textAreaEmail").find('textarea').attr('name', 'body');`

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Without jQuery it won't be much more complicated: document.querySelector("#textAreaEmail textarea").setAttribute('name', 'body');

Comment: @paokg4 Actually you can do this, but it's a very bad practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: @Admit I agree because it needs to traverse the whole DOM (best practice is to give an `ID` attr to the `textarea` and do directly on this element anything) but the OP has specific structure and he asked a specific thing. I just commented on what he had wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `attribute` `name` to the value `body` then do:

```
$("#textAreaEmail").find('textarea').attr('name', 'body');
```

You need to use `#` to use id as a selector.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work when I add # on it.

Comment: But anyways, `find` worked pretty well! Without adding the # tho.

Comment: I am assuming that multiple HTML elements does not share the same id. IS it correct?

Comment: @JanArielSanJose then maybe you are storing the id in some variable. Anyways if it solves your problem then do mark this answer correct...

Comment: That was so dumb of me, I actually forgot to enclose it on ` ' ' `.

Comment: I'll mark this answer correct in 4 minutes, Stackoverflow won't let me accept it instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way but I'm not sure where you have `hidden` attribute but I followed your question:

```
$("#textAreaEmail").removeAttr('hidden').find('textarea').attr('name', 'body'); // If hidden attribute under parent div
$("#textAreaEmail").find('textarea').removeAttr('hidden').attr('name', 'body'); // If hidden attribute under textarea
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "#" symbol for the ID and the quotes in your two selectors, so...

```
$(textAreaEmail).removeAttr('hidden');
```

...should be

```
$('#textAreaEmail').removeAttr('hidden');
```